# Creating a Generic array without using Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

In order to complete one of my Java assignments, I have to do what seems like the impossible.

I have to create a method that takes in different stuff and plugs it into an array. We don't necessarily know what is being put into the array and thus the array must be able to accept `String`s, `Double`, `Integer`, etc...

Of course, the obvious solution would be to use `ArrayList<E>` (i.e. a generic array). However, that's partly the complication of the problem. We cannot use an `ArrayList`, only a regular array. As far as I can find, when creating an array its intake value must be declared. Which leads me to believe that this assignment is impossible (yet I doubt the teacher would give me an impossible assignment).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with the objects in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use an array of `Object` - `Object[]`.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[2];
objects[0] = "ABC";
objects[1] = Integer.valueOf("15");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a *generic* array or an array that can hold anything?

If the former, then create a class that will act as wrapper of `Object[] array` and use a `<T>` generic for type cast when getting the elements of the array, which is similar to the implementation of `ArrayList` class. If the latter, use `Object[]` directly.